Does not transfer data between activities. Issues a nuul #Kotlin
Main activities:
    val message = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvText)
    val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.tvName)
    val sumbit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSubmit)
    val next = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnNext)
    var Name = ""


    sumbit.setOnClickListener() {
        Name = name.text.toString()
        if (Name == "") {
            message.text = "Write name"

        } else {
            next.visibility = VISIBLE
            message.text = "Hello $Name"
            name.text.clear()

            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "All good",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).
            show()
        }
    }
    next.setOnClickListener(){
        val lastScreen = Intent(this, SecondActivity :: class.java)
        intent.putExtra("UserName", Name)
        startActivity(lastScreen)
    }
}

}
Second:
    val user = intent.getStringExtra("UserName")
    val usName = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.USname)
    val mes = "$user good boy"
    usName.text = mes

Result:
nuul good boy
I don't even know what to try. This is my first project.I hope for the help of professionals.I don't want to give up this case

post your stacktrace, please, it usually says what is null

Each findViewById() call could return a null. Then, calls like setOnClickListener will crash with nullpointer.
First of all you need to examine the stacktrace to find out, which line crashes.
Try to debug your code with breakpoints or logs to see, which object is null.
